# Adding &#160; into xml using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I want to add triple spacing in my xml but browser is changing triple spacing to single. I have found `&#160;`  to be used to include spacing. I have a tab delimited text file and i am converting it to xml using php. In order to have triple spacing inside my title node i am doing like this.

```
 $xml->startElement('Products');
    while ($line = fgetcsv($fp, 0, "\t")) {

        $xml->startElement('Product');
        //replacing titlesingle space to triple space
        $title = str_replace(" ", "&#160;&#160;&#160;", $line[1]);
        $xml->writeElement('title', $title);
        .....
        $xml->endElement();
    }
    $xml->endElement();
}
```

But is `&#160;` changed to `&amp;#160;` and title is something like this

```
<title>A&amp;#160;&amp;#160;&amp;#160;Test</title>
```

Basically php is changing & to amp but i want exact   so that i can have triple spacing in the title

```
<title>A   Test</title>
```

Any help??

Comment: is this inside a loop? could you show the codes? and which xml parser are you using? `SimpleXML`, `XmlWriter`?

Comment: i am using XMLWriter

Comment: right now i am doing it through Dreamweaver replace to search all triple spacing and replace with  &#160;&#160;&#160; which is working fine but i need to automate this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not change the spacing. But in HTML/XML several whitespaces are usually (not always) rendered as a single space or a linebreak.

`#160;` is the non breaking space. One of the uses is to separate the parts of a phone number. You don't want one of the spaces in a phone number rendered as a linebreak.

The UTF-8 bytes for this character are `\xC2\xA0`.

```
$xml->writeElement('foo', "foo\xC2\xA0&\xC2\xA0bar");
```

If the XML document is encoding is ASCII, they will get encoded as entities.

```
$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'ASCII');

$xml->writeElement('foo', "foo\xC2\xA0&\xC2\xA0bar");

$xml->endDocument();
echo $xml->outputMemory(TRUE);
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ASCII"?>
<foo>foo&#160;&amp;&#160;bar</foo>
```